# iPhone Launch Image zoom animation not working on physical device

Tags: iphone, image, zooming, launch

I have developed an iPhone app with a launch image. When starting the app in the simulator, the image zooms in as expected. However, when the app is deployed to my physical device, the zoom animation is very short and sometimes completes instantaneously.

I'm sure it's nothing to do with my app start up as I put a sleep call in applicationDidFinishLoading to slow it down and this occurs after the zoom animation has completed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Has nothing to do with your startup image. Has everything to do with the speed of your device and what you're loading on starting. If you're not loading much at startup the animation will be very fast, especially on a 3GS device.

Comment: I think I initially misunderstood your response as I thought you were referring to work I was doing in applicationDidFinishLoading. Reading your answer again seems to match my observations below.

Answer (score 0):

I tracked this down to the fact I have a large number of resources. Either the number of files (2400) or the combined size of them is causing a pause before the start up image is shown.